# Write NDArray into JSON and .CV File

Tags: python, json, csv, file-io, numpy

I have an ndarray of size 9742 rown x 26 columns. It has types like date, integers, floats etc. and column headers like "Date", "Amount","Marks" and so on.... The thing is, I wanted to save it row by row into another file. I was hoping if you'll could possibly help me with doing this.

I tried using:

```
for k1 in range(1,len(arr)):
    c.writerow([arr[index[1:27]][k1]])
```

But it gives me an unhashable type error. index is a python map which I use to loop through the column headings, as in 1: "Date", 2: "Amount" and so on...

I also would like to possibly write it to a JSON file. I have no experience with JSON though. I'd much appreciate it if you'll could please help me with it.

Comment: We need more information on your array.  Is it a structured array with 26 fields in the dtype?  Does index[1:27] return those field names?

Comment: Oh the dtype is: datetime.datetime, int, float so on... I hope that answers the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using [`numpy.savetext()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) instead of trying to write each line manually.  In that case, you can use:

```
numpy.savetxt(filename, arr, header=arr.dtype.names)
```

You could also try converting the thing you're writing into a string by using something like:

```
for arr_row in arr:
    c.writerow(" ".join(map(str, arr_row)))
```